# How to properly destroy a UDP Socket in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, c++11, qt5

I'm working with QT UDP Sockets. This Socket are part of a "communication" class called, say, Com. It happens, for the needs of my application, that Com need to be deleted. Now, my question is: is it sufficient to invoke `delete myUdpSocket;` or should I explicitly invoke `flush()`, 'close()` or whatever? I ask this because when I delete Com the application does not necessairly need to close but instead it it possible that a new Instance of om need to be instantiated and with that a new instance of a UDP Socket on the same port and at the same addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, deleting the QUdpSocket will close it (and unbind) automatically.

This means that you can create a new instance later on the same port and address.